# On clicking Gridview row update another control

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have data coming from the service that has 7 columns. I can show them all in the grid view but I like to know how to show 2 of those columns in another control may be textblock. 
So when someone clicks on the row, the second control will be updated with information in the other two columns. 
I tried to use this in my MVVM

```
</ListView.View>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OnRowClickCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListView>
```

Has anyone tried to do this before ? Any examples would be great help.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was very simple.. Here it is if anyone else wants to know. Did not need event handler etc.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=ListViewName,Path=SelectedItem.Column}"/>
```

However I am not sure currently how I can conditionally show a label for this information..